# Push to Heroku changes the modified date of unmodified file

Tags: python, git, heroku, git-push

I have a project on Heroku with a file, say `test.csv`. I didn't make any change to this .csv file, but to my `main.py` file. When I do `git push heroku master` and try to retrieve the modified date of the `test.csv` via:

```
time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime('test.csv'))
```

I get the date/time of the push to heroku instead of the actual last modified date/time. I also have this project in GitHub, and the modified date/time is correct in on the website.

Wondering why it does this, and if there's any way I could get the actual last modified date of a file in Heroku.

---

Edit: From talking to @VonC, it appears that what I need is to get the date that the file was last committed, not modified, as the modified date will get changed every time a commit happens. Will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned before that [Git does not record timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964508/6309).
What you would get locally is the timestamp of the last clone or checkout.

Check with `git show` if the last commit (pushed to heroku) did include test.csv.
Even if you did not modify it directly, a setting like git config core.autocrlf might have changed it automatically.

In python:

- "[How to get last commit for specified file with python(dulwich)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16642203/6309)"
- "[Get time of last commit for Git repository files via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13104495/6309)"

Comment: Sorry I'm not very familiar with `git`. Tried doing `git show heroku master` but that doesn't work. How do I do that? What got me curious is that the repo in GitHub and in Heroku should be very similar, but the one in GitHub got the correct date.

Comment: @Art Again, the date seen locally is the one of the last clone/checkout, not the one of the remote repository. And assuming the last commit is the one pushed to heroku, a simply git show (no argument) would be enough.

Comment: Checked... `test.csv` doesn't appear on `git show`.

Comment: @Art Then as mentioned at the beginning of the answer, the timestamp seen if the one of the last local clone/checkout, since Git itself does not record timestamps.

Comment: So you're saying that GitHub's ability to show last modified date for each file is GitHub's own feature?

Comment: @Art on GitHub, you see the timestamp of the last commit, not the last modification. A file can have been modified 3 days ago, but committed 3 seconds ago: the latter time will be seen on GitHub. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195616/6309.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199553/discussion-between-art-and-vonc).